# Display an image having A4 size in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I am working on a project and in that I have to show image to user. Actually the image is dynamically created bitmap images (A4 size page and has to print to A4 page)and sometimes it has more than one pages and I have to give a preview to user . So how can I do this in a windows application with out a third party application? or is there anything that will be a better solution than this. But I have to create this bitmap image to create that page in all the situation.

Comment: Have you considered using WPF and the DocumentViewer in combination with a FixedDocument. You can put your images in a container on a FixedPage and stuff your FixedDocument in the DocumentViewer. You get scaling, zooming, etc for Free ;)

Comment: My image is dynamically creating and its not saving anywhere. Can you guide me with some more information?

Comment: The following links should give a first impression and some material to get you started: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mamta_m/working-with-fixeddocuments-in-wpf/ & http://wpf.2000things.com/2011/03/25/256-use-a-fixeddocument-to-display-content-at-fixed-locations/

Comment: Any basic knowledge of WPF will be very useful ;)

Answer (score 2):

A4 is a paper size with 210 × 297mm.

Bitmaps are created in various way, but they one way or another always need a pixel size, eg . 210 × 297 pixels.

To create an A4 Bitmap you also need to decide on the resolution, eg 100dpi or 800dpi..

```
float mmpi = 25.4f;
int dpi = 150;
Bitmap A4 = new Bitmap( (int) (210/mmpi*dpi), (int)(297/mmpi*dpi) );
A4.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);
```

This will result in a Bitmap of 1240.1 x 1753.9 pixels with 150dpi; you can get it directly like this:

```
Bitmap A4 = new Bitmap(1240, 1754)
A4.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);
```

To preview a `Bitmap` you simply assign it to the `Image` of a `PictureBox` control:

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
pictureBox1.Image = A4;
```

Notes:

- You will run into memory problems when you try to create a Bitmap that's too great.
  Even going to 200dpi will throw an exception.
- You may want to reduce the physical size by leaving off the margins.
- There are quite a few things to consider when you print the Bitmap..
- Chances are that you won't be able to create more than one such big image at a time. You may need to store one to disk before you create the 2nd one.
- The above code will produce an image fit for printing. Obviously this is way too large to display in a preview. For that purpose you will either have to scale it down or create another one for display sizes, maybe 280x351 pixels. This will probably be the better option. You will have one Paint event for the display control and one for the print document anyway..

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I did the page creation  and now I need to show that image to user.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? BTW, there is a nice PrintPreview control, too

Comment: 1 inch is equal 25.4mm or 2.54cm. so your calculation is wrong! (the variable `mmpi` should be equal `25.4f`)